# PHP Array_intersect on multidimensional array with unknown number of keys

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-intersect

I'm trying to make advanced search filters in an application that holds resources (people). I've got all the results in 1 multidimensional array. A user of the application can search for the persons Job title, skills, work field and country.

I've already made the part where I look up the people that meet the criteria given by the user. These results are stored in a multidimensional array. If the user is looking for someone with a specific resource with a job title and a specific skill the return value is this:

```
$realfilters = array(2) {
["resourcesWithJobtitle"]=> array(6) {
   [0]=> string(1) "1"
   [1]=> string(2) "48"
   [2]=> string(2) "88"
}
["resourcesWithSkill"]=> array(9) {
   [0]=> string(1) "4"
   [1]=> string(1) "8"
   [2]=> string(1) "48"
   [3]=> string(2) "50"
}
```

When the user also looks for a work field this is added to the result:

```
["resourcesWithWorkfield"]=> array(3) {
   [0]=> string(2) "48"
   [1]=> string(2) "96"
   [2]=> string(2) "97"
}
```

I need to know which resources meet all dimensions of the array so I can display them. (So in this example I need an array with just 1 value: 48). I think I need to use `array_intersect` but can't seem to get it right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the possible solutions: you may first [`extract()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) the `$realfilters` array values to variables, and then apply the `array_intersect()` to them. But this solution is applicable only if there are not many possible filters.

Another one and probably the best solution would be to intersect in a loop, something like:

```
$res_arr = array_shift($realfilters);
foreach($realfilters as $filter){
     $res_arr = array_intersect($res_arr, $filter);
}
```

Comment: Seems like the way to go but isn't working:
[code]if(!empty($realfilters))
{
 
 $resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera = $realfilters[0];
 for ($i = 1; $i < count($realfilters); $i++) 
 {
  $resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera = array_intersect_key($resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera, $realfilters[$i]);
 }
 
 var_dump($resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera); // empty 
}[/code]

Comment: Got it. $realfilters[0] doesn't work. Changed it to $realfilters["resourcesWithJobtitle"] and now it works!

Comment: Yeah. Just noticed that also :)
But better solution just came to my mind (in case you don't know the key):

$resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera = array_shift($realfilters);
foreach($realfilters as $filter){ 
$resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera = array_intersect($resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera, $filter);
}

Comment: @MettinParzinski by the way, why do you use array_intersect_key? keys are just indexes (0,1,2) in your case...

Comment: That's a mistake. This is my final code:
if(!empty($realfilters))
{
 $resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera = $allResourceIDs;

 foreach ($realfilters as $key => $value)
 {
  $resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera = array_intersect($resourceIDsThatMatchAllCritera, $realfilters[$key]);
 }
}

Comment: OK, I see. Anyway, I think that the most clean & nice and also universal solution was offered by @chris :)

Answer (score 4):

```
$intersection = call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array);
```

That will give you the elements present in *all* the sub arrays of $array.

edit-
This above is like a shortcut for writing:

```
$intersection = array_intersect($array['a'], $array['b'], ...and so on for all elements...);
```

A loop could be used as well

```
$intersection = reset($array);
foreach ($array as $subarr) {
    $intersection = array_intersect($intersection, $subarr);
}
print_r($intersection);
```